# array walking the $_POST variable in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, post, str-replace, double-quotes

I need to remove double quotes from any possible post value.   I currently have this code:

```
array_walk($_POST, create_function('&$val', '$val = str_replace(chr(34), chr(39), $val);'));
```

The problem is that its not working as expected.   So if a post input box is set to the following when posted...

> A " Test

The resulting post variable I get after running the array walk instead contains a slash chr !?!  Ie...

> A \' Test

Instead of

> A Test

Can anyone suggest what's going on here ?

Answer (score 0):

the code is doing what you ask it to, replace `"` with `'`.

to remove the `"` change your code to

```
array_walk($_POST, create_function('&$val', '$val = str_replace(chr(34), "", $val);'));
```

which replaces the `"` with nothing

demo: http://ideone.com/FBIWkW

Comment: Hi nogad, the problem is the slash.   Why is that there?

Comment: nothing in your code does this, i suggest you may have the old and dangerous `magic quotes` enabled on server http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

Comment: No I'm using a recent php v7 without magic quotes.   It's most odd, im still getting this slash, even if i remove my quote chr replacing it with "" as you suggested.   So now I see: A \ Test

Comment: well its still nothing to do with code posted, it has to be added elsewhere